# Does Javascript supports Sets?

Tags: javascript, collections, set, duplicates, no-duplicates

Does Javascript supports Sets(list with unique objects only) ?

I have found [this link](http://community.service-now.com/blog/slightlyloony/4113), but from what I remember foreach in JS in not supported by every browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are your keys strings?

Every JavaScript object is a map, which means that it can represent a set.

As illustrated in the  page you mentioned, each object will accept only one copy of each key (attribute name). The value for the key/attribute doesn't matter.

Comment: The article you link is the same page 01 linked to.

Comment: thx for clarification, ive just found that article very hard to read, so I tried to guess what he meant :P

Answer (score 4):

[jshashtable](http://www.timdown.co.uk/jshashtable/) would allow you to store any object as a key, and use the same pattern as in the link you gave. In addition it supplies a method to get an array of keys, which you can then iterate over. It also has good cross-browser support, so should fit nicely into any environment.

Comment: thx for the link, i have also found that, but if I can use a map for that than using external lib is not needed.

Comment: A map won't work out of the box for non-string objects, which is the point of jshashtable.

Comment: In case it's not clear, there is a `HashSet` wrapper available to download with jshashtable: http://code.google.com/p/jshashtable/downloads/detail?name=jshashset.js&can=2&q=#makechanges

Answer (score 2):

Now with ES6 (and polyfills/shims like [corejs](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js)) you have them:

[Set - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Example:

```js
var mySet = new Set([1, 2, 3, 2, 1]);  // => [1, 2, 3]
console.log(mySet.size);
console.log(mySet.has(3));
mySet.forEach(function(x){console.log(x)});
```

The Polifill is required since it is not supported by older browsers, so you can ignore it if you are aiming only at the latest ones.

Answer (score 0):

You probably remember the `Array.forEach()` that is indeed not supported by older Opera and all IE browsers - the `for (var x in ...)` is part of the "native" JS as far as I know and is supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript do support Set. Here is the [link](https://caniuse.com/?search=new%20Set()) to canIuse website. It is supported by Chrome, Edge, Safari, Firefox, Opera and even IE. To declare set you can use Set() constructor.

```
let set = new Set();
set.add("John);
```

In this way you can use sets.